What should the pilots and ATC do if a passenger forgot her baby at the airport?
Recently I saw an article about how a mother forgot her baby at the terminal. After they had already taken-off and climbing, she suddenly realizes that she forgot her baby. According to many sources, she "refused to continue the flight" (to be honest, I don't know what that's supposed to mean; I'll probably post that as another question). The pilots requested permission from ATC and turned back. Now, my question is, are the pilots required to turn back in such a scenario, or can they choose not to turn back? Also, will ATC put the aircraft's priority at the bottom of the incoming traffic list, or it this some kind of urgency flight that ATC must prioritize over normal flights (but below emergency flights, of course)? I'm asking this in a case where there's no safety concerns if they do return, but the pilots and ATC doesn't want the aircraft to turn back and delay others just because of this.
EDIT: The originally linked articles used as reference are not trustworthy and reliable, so I replaced them with a single, more trustworthy source (a The Guardian article). I hope this makes this post more fact-based, clearer, and useful and answerable.

Most of this isn't really covered by aviation regulations and should probably be asked on Law.SE (similar to your recent question). The only on-topic part of this question I see is "can ATC deny the aircraft from returning, or are they generally required to grant permission?"

Also, I'm very very skeptical this is real. All the links go back to the same article, and the supposed "viral video" is no longer on youtube. Lets find out the truth

FYI, I downvoted because (among other reasons...) the answer calls for speculation about what they "should" do without enough detail to form a valid subjective opinion.  (Is it an emergency because they were left in a car in the hot sun in the parking lot?   Or is the baby in the custody of gate agents who are providing adequate care?)  Not really answerable as-is, and not a good fit for this site.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


What should the pilots and ATC do if a passenger forgot her baby at the airport?

Answering on the principle, as this kind of story is in general at best distorted, as worth totally false. You expect people here to provide fact-checked elements, people here also expect fact-checked questions.
ATC role and reaction to a change of plan
You seem to have a misconception of ATC role. ATC doesn't tell aircraft where to go. They ensure aircraft separation and provide information related to the safety of flight, like other aircraft in the vicinity and weather.
Assuming returning to the origin airport is feasible and this is the decision taken by the crew, ATC will facilitate the change of plan. This means some rerouting will take place using a safe flight path preventing any collisions with other aircraft. ATC will take care of this according to the pilot request. It may be more complex than a simple 180° turn at constant altitude.
Crew decision
It's obvious when considering the impact of a diversion in term of inconvenience for the passengers and the operator, and in term of cost for the operator, the aircraft will not divert. There are airport and operator employees, and authorities who are able to deal with the problem, this doesn't require the mother to be present.
The operator employees on the ground will just call the airport where the baby is and ensure someone will take care of the baby, until the mother or someone else is able to go to the airport.
Authority of the pilot-in-command
As soon as the doors are closed, the PIC has a large authority on the passengers in order to ensure the security of the flight. The fact the mother is not accepting to continue the flight is an element which has little impact on the PIC decision, motivated only by the baby own situation. From SKYbrary:

ICAO Annex 2, par. 2.3.1, specifically empowers the PIC to override any other regulation in an emergency, and to take the safest course of action at his/her sole discretion. This provision mirrors the authority given to the captains of ships at sea, with similar justifications. It essentially gives the PIC the final authority in any situation involving the safety of a flight, irrespective of any other law or regulation.

Aeronautical rules inherit from marine rule. Nobody imagines a ship would return to the port of origin after a couple of days of navigation because a baby has been forgotten.

Hmm. (point 1 is just pedantic: ATC can tell pilots not to flight on some areas). Point 2: authority: it is ok, but PIC having authority doesn't mean PIC is above law or PIC has full discretion. It just means that PIC has full control, but later laws/companies can intervene. Point 3- If a stowaway is found, ship companies usually requires ships to return if they are around 2 to 4 days away: it can be much cheaper. If a baby is found on a ship, they will return also much later. The contrary case it is just seldom: ships with long tracks without ports will not allows baby anyway.

@GiacomoCatenazzi: Yes, but formally the objectives of ATC are only to: "prevent collisions between aircraft, expedite and maintain an orderly flow of air traffic,  provide advice and information useful for the safe and efficient conduct of flights, notify appropriate organizations regarding aircraft in need of search and rescue aid, and assist such organizations as required." (Annex 11). My point was there is nothing like "prohibiting to return", or  "air police" in ATC objectives, only clearance, advice and information.

The short answer is that Federal Aviation Regulations do not require either Air Traffic Controllers or Pilots in Command to take responsibility for the consequences of passenger negligence, or the negative consequences of passenger inactions, on the ground either before or after flight.
This may sound a little cold and heartless in the case of an infant, but where would you draw the line?  Could a passenger declare that they are unwilling to continue because they forgot to turn the coffeepot off back home?  Or because their traveling companion was in the restroom during boarding and missed the flight?
Now, there may be a way to force the issue as a passenger if you become unruly enough, but there will be consequences...
The best course of action involves judgment, not regulation.  A good option for the crew might have been to relay the situation to dispatch to ensure the infant is well cared for, continue the flight, and let the passenger deal with the logistics of ensuring longer term care and reuniting with their baby later.

I'm wide open to feedback from downvoters...
